# ProcessBuilder giver error "Cannot find symbol" for classes in the same package

Tags: java, client-server, processbuilder

I am creating a client-server application with sockets that when the server dies a client needs to restart the server so it can continue using the application and other users can connect to it. I am trying to restart this using the ProcessBuilder and this is my code so far:

```
 public void restartServer() {
        String command[] = {"javac",SERVER_FILE_LOCATION};
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);

        try {
            Process process = processBuilder.start();

            if( process.getErrorStream().read() != -1 ){
                print("Compilation Errors",process.getErrorStream());
            }
            if( process.exitValue() != 0 ) {
                process = new ProcessBuilder(
                        new String[]{
                                "java",
                                "-cp",
                                "D:\\CE303\\Lab4\\assignment\\src\\Server\\",
                                "ServerProgram"}).start();

                if (process.getErrorStream().read() != -1) {
                    System.out.println("Errors " + process.getErrorStream());
                }
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Output " + process.getInputStream());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

The print function is a function that deals with the error and prints it. And I get the error:

```
************* Compilation Errors***********************
:\CE303\Lab4\assignment\src\Server\ServerProgram.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
    private static final Market market = new Market();
                         ^
  symbol:   class Market
  location: class ServerProgram
D:\CE303\Lab4\assignment\src\Server\ServerProgram.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
    private static final Market market = new Market();
                                             ^
  symbol:   class Market
  location: class ServerProgram
D:\CE303\Lab4\assignment\src\Server\ServerProgram.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
                new Thread(new Server.ClientHandler(socket, market)).start();
                                     ^
  symbol:   class ClientHandler
  location: package Server
3 errors
```

For some reason the Server can't recognize these classes even though they are in the same package and they are public. I am unsure what to do I don't know if I need to add something to the environment map or anything else.

EDIT: I added th class that I am trying to run with ProcessBuilder. That class runs fine if I run it from IntelliJ but gives me the errors above if I do it thorugh ProcessBuilder.

```
package Server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerProgram
{
    private final static int port = 8888;

    private static final Market market = new Market();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        RunServer();
    }

    private static void RunServer() {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Waiting for incoming connections...");
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                new Thread(new Server.ClientHandler(socket, market)).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not in the code that you showed us.  The problem is actually just a regular java compilation error in some other code.  I'm not sure why you showed us that code at all.

Comment: I used this tutorial to try and run ProcessBuilder. https://itexpertsconsultant.wordpress.com/2016/01/29/how-to-run-external-java-program-by-using-processbuilder/. @Abra

Comment: This is still not making sense.  The problem is occurring when you compile the code.  Your process builder code does not compile the code.

Comment: But I don't get why I get the 3 errors "Cannot find symbol" for the Market and ClientHandler classes. Doesn't that mean that for some reason the ProcessBuilder doesn't reach the classes?

Comment: `String command[] = {"javac",SERVER_FILE_LOCATION};` Why do you need to recompile your code in order to restart the server?

Comment: The SERVER_FILE_LOCATION is pointing to a .java file. I am not sure how else to do it I just used the instructions from that link.

Comment: I assume that all of your java code is already compiled before you run your application. If that is true, then there is no need to recompile. You only need to recompile if you change the source code. Again, I assume you aren't changing source code when the server dies. Just delete the `javac` command. There is no need for it. Have you read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) for class `ProcessBuilder`?

Comment: I managed to do it yeah I deleted the javac command and I just run the application from the out folder.